# How to force route in folder to be at /index in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have a project that has to have specific url naming like so

```
example.com/desktop/index
example.com/mobile/index
```

I am trying to use Nuxt for this. I thought it would be simple enough to create two folders, one desktop and one mobile, each with an index file. But Nuxt automatically sets the route of any index file in a folder to that folder's name. So my file structure looks like this

```
pages
  desktop
    index.vue
  mobile
    index.vue
```

and the routes come out as

```
example.com/desktop
example.com/mobile
```

Does anyone know how I can force the /index to show in the url?

Answer (score 2):

You can put `index.vue` in a directory called `index`:

```
pages
  desktop
    index
      index.vue
  mobile
    index
      index.vue
```